# Making bricks out of bread

Tags: internal-consistency, construction

Some kinds of bread get hard as time passes by. These kinds that harden usually stay soft for no longer than a day after being baked. I've once forgotten a loaf of bread for about a week on a shelf - I needed a saw to cut it in two.

I think such bread only gets harder as time goes by. Can bread become so hard that we could make bricks and build houses out of it, though?

If regular bread won't do, can we add some readily available food product to the dough to enable such use?

I don't care if it takes years to reach brick-grade hardness and tenacity.

**Edit:** thanks for the comments about water, guys. Imagine that we're going to use this technology in a pretty dry place, though.

Comment: You may find issues with rain, cold and birbs.

Comment: Several cultures used what was essentially seriously overbaked bread for traveling supplies.  They would boil it in water to make soup.  So even after hardened enough to last months, it still softens in water.

Comment: @JoeBloggs I agree about rain and cold, but I intend to build the tree house for the kids only after the bread is hard enough to be impervious to them critters. That should be safe as long as there are no woodpeckers around.

Comment: You can make houses out of any solid if you distribute the weight enough.  Mice might be a problem, though.

Comment: I do not think it is possible. I am by no means food chemist, but surely it can not harden without limit as time goes on. I would bet that it actually stops hardening well before brick hardness

Comment: Even in the desert, it occasionally rains.

Comment: Some Dwarf Bread may do the trick for ya... https://wiki.lspace.org/mediawiki/Dwarf_Bread

Comment: but why? bread is quite hard to make. If they have trees, they will have planks or at least sticks that are much easier to get.

Comment: @BaldBear I never saw people questioning why elves should have no anus, why Ch'tullu should need a private company or the the design of creatures that fly by farting, or what foods should werewolves avoid. I am sincerely amazed that a question that has a concrete, real life application should get more questioning than those. I'm amazed in a positive, fun way though.

Comment: How is this about world building?

Comment: @Renan worldbuilding is all about the creation of a fictional world, frequently including elements that do not exist in the real one.  Questions here are generally about how to make the things that are different fit with eachother, and the things they didn't change.  Your question doesn't contain any reference to a world, or even a story you are trying to create.  It feels more like an "I wonder if that could happen".  I'm willing to give you the benefit of the doubt here, but that's probably why people are questioning if this is the right place for this question to be asked, IMO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bread is made using flour, water and salt.

With the same ingredients, different proportions, one can do [salt dough](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_dough)

> Salt dough is a modelling material made from a mixture of flour, salt and water. It can be used to make ornaments and sculptures, and can be dried in the oven or microwave. It can be sealed using varnish or polyurethane, and can be painted with acrylic paint, or coloured using food colouring, natural colouring, or paint mixed in with the flour or water.
>
> Properly mixed dough does not crumble or crack. It is a dense, and hence heavy, material, which can cause issues with large designs. It can be moulded by hand, without using special tools or fixtures, and it does not stain hands. More complex sculptures can be made using basic tools.

I guess it can be used to make bricks, too. And then stack the bricks as you would do with normal bricks.

Comment: One relative of mine used that to make ornaments. We never tried to make bricks out of it, but certainly it was not very strong.

Answer (score 3):

What your essentially looking to build your building out of is hardtack. [Hardtack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardtack) has around 100 year shelf-life,  So you absolutely could build a house from this.  Just don't spill any hot water on the walls.

I can't find anything on how high you can stack hardtack on itself or how much weight it can hold.  I imagine at the bottom of the wall it might become more like sand.

This sort of structure would have interesting secondary benefits such as being relatively non-flammable, decently good insulation, and a source of food during famine.

Answer (score 3):

## How to prepare building bread

The other answers talk about what sorts of bread to use, but I'm going to give some tips on how to prepare bread for long term, construction use:

- Don't use yeast. Yeast makes bread rise; rising adds porosity increasing surface area and increasing the ability to absorb moisture. Since you don't want that, make [unleavened bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unleavened_bread), not allowing time to rise between dough preparation and baking.
- Use much gluten. Gluten is the protein chain that binds bread together; it makes dough 'sticky.' Use as much gluten as possible. Wheat has the most gluten of any common grain, and it is possible to concentrate gluten itself. If you [wash flour to remove starch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheat_gluten_(food)), you can increase the gluten concentration.
- Bake many times. Hardtack, as used by the British Navy, was baked four times. Keep baking to completely dessicate the interior and give the exterior a hardened finish.